# Is there a way to navigate pages white keeping the same background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a flutter app where I'm mainly keeping the background the same and the pages that the user uses just stack up on top of the background. Is there any way to navigate from one screen to another whilst keeping the background the same? My main layout for this app is a Stack widget where i keep my background widget there and the widget on top is the one we want to navigate out off.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for something like pageview

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

simple setstate Example, with a counter

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("simple setstate Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _counter == 0 ? new Page1() : new Container(),
            _counter == 1 ? new Page2() : new Container(),
            _counter == 2 ? new Page3() : new Container(),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 200.0,
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: 200.0,
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {


@override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  double opacityLevel = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() => opacityLevel = opacityLevel == 1 ? 0.0 : 1.0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: opacityLevel,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 200.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sort of, I want that but with different transitions, like tapping a button to take you to the next page rather than a scroll, but thanks for the idea anyway!

Comment: I also don't want the pages to follow any order but rather follow whatever path the user decides to take using the direction buttons

Comment: you can do it with a simple variable, that changes with setstate when you tapping the button

Comment: Can you explain a little about this or link some examples please

Comment: see the new version of my answer :D

Comment: would there be any way to change the animation of how to new pages appear?

Comment: page3 is now animated, but it gives many many animations in flutter

Comment: okay, so i've tried doing it like you have (with a variable) but when i tap a button to change state nothing happens... I know I'm changing the variable correctly because I print it and if I hot reload the app it will change to the new page but for whatever reason, just tapping on the button doesn't update anything...